# Angular. Как передать данные из object - attachment?

Tags: java, angularjs, angularjs-controller

В общем есть что то типа конструктора PDF, заполняем поля и по нажатию на "предварительный просмотр" данные из этих полей должны быть в PDF-ке

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.order.attachment.salutation">
```

Из этого input'a данные хранятся в object'e, вопрос в том, как вытянуть данные из объекта этого и отправить в PDF файл?

```
var vm = this;
    vm.CurrentOrder = CurrentOrder;
    vm.order = CurrentOrder.order;
vm.generatePdf = function () {
            ServicePDF.save(vm.order, function (result) {
                var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);
            });
        }
```

Comment: 1. Код следует добавлять текстом, а лучше вообще [mcve] сделать. 2. Вообще не понял, в чём заключается проблема.

Comment: Немного подправил

Comment: ну так твой vm.order Ты уже используешь

Comment: ну в vm.order есть attachment'ы, и вот данные этих attachment = данным в input, как мне отправлять эти данные при функции generatePDF

Comment: куда отправлять? ты же уже передаешь параметр в функцию: `ServicePDF.save(vm.order`. Внутри функции у тебя полный доступ ко всему объекту, хочешь бери _attachment_ - хочешь нет